# How do I make error alerts continue to appear every time there is a validation error and not just once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap to build a custom alert component to display client-side validation errors. The following is the code for this custom error alert component.

```
const ErrorAlert = ({errorMessage}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  
  if(show) {
    return (
      <Alert variant="danger" style={{ marginLeft: "25%", marginRight: "25%" }} onClose={() => setShow(false)} dismissible>
      {errorMessage}
    </Alert>
    )
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  
}
```

After the page containing the form loads my error message alert appears as expected and also disappears as expected on clicking the built-in close button on the React Bootstrap alert component. However, when I try reproducing the validation error without page refresh the custom error alert component does not appear. The following is the relevant code for the component that contains the form.

```
const AddUser = ({ user }) => {
  
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  
  async function createUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);
    if (
      !formData.fullName ||
      !formData.companyName ||
      !formData.address1 ||
      !formData.city ||
      !formData.state ||
      !formData.zip ||
      !formData.country
    ) {
      setErrorMessage("Fields marked with * are required.");
      console.log(errorMessage);
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      return;
    }

  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "3%" }}>
        Complete your profile
      </h1>
      {errorMessage && <ErrorAlert errorMessage={errorMessage} />}
      <Form
        style={{
          marginTop: "5%",
          marginLeft: "25%",
          marginRight: "25%",
        }}
        onSubmit={createUser}
      >
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help me fix this bug.

Comment: `After the page containing the form loads my error message alert appears as expected` Are you sure this is as expected? `errorMessage && <ErrorAlert errorMessage={errorMessage} />` I would have thought `errorMessage` would not be set on page load, therefore the `ErrorAlert` component shouldn't show? Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: The ErrorAlert component displays when a client-side validation error occurs. But the issue is that it displays only once. When I try to recreate the error without refreshing the page the ErrorAlert does not display again.

Comment: `const [show, setShow] = useState(true); if(show) { ... }` you are not setting `show` to true anywhere, this is likely the problem, you need to combine this with if there is an error message